# xCode cannot run using the selected device error!

Tags: iphone, xcode4

All of a sudden I am getting the following error when I try to run the app on the device.

"xCode cannot run using the selected device" No provisioned iOS devices are available. Connect an iOS device or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

If I see in the organizer I get the following information: 
[image]

UPDATE: I tried running one of my old applications and it worked fine. The dropdown which shows if the app is running on simulator or device automatically gets populated when I run my old app. It list my device name correctly. When I try to run my new app then it only shows iosdevice option and simulator option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XCode 4 has a fun little bug, here's how you might fix it:

Check what version of iOS SDK you have selected under your target.  Click on the project in the nav tree, then summary.  You should see a 'deployment target'.  If that's in grey, then it's being auto filled.  For some reason, this causes the 'no provisioned device' error.

(Edited:  You tagged for XCode 4, so no reason to say 'if you're running...')

By click on project, etc etc, I mean the following:

Use the navigation tree you have to select different files to edit, and scroll to the top of it.  At the top should be a blue XCode icon labeled file (that acts as a directory, I know) with the name of the project.  Click on that.  In the window that opens on the right, you should see a tab bar with a tab labeled 'summary'.  Under summary, check the deployment target.

Comment: I am not able to follow your answer. Please check my updated question.

Comment: I just selected the iOS Deployment Target from 4.3 to 4.0.1 and now it seems to be working fine. Weird!

Comment: What part aren't you following?  I'm editing for a bit of clarity now, but I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Woops, looks like our comments crossed in the mail.  But if you manually set it to 4.3, I bet you it will still work fine -- for some reason, when it auto-sets to 4.3, that's just a 'default' value and won't work.  If you manually set 4.3, it's a 'real' value and everything is peachy-keen.

Comment: Got it now! Thanks! I should have set the deployment target to the earliest version. xCode was looking for 4.3 while my iPhone was running 4.0.1 and thats why it was refusing to run on the device.

Answer (score 1):

You may have already tried this, but I've found that this kind of thing is often solved by unplugging/restarting the device, and quitting/restarting Xcode.  If that fails, I'd look at project OS version settings, provisioning profiles on the device (expired?), etc.

Comment: I restarted the device and Mac and still the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

I have solve the problem using the below steps.

Close the Xcode

Delete the application from device

Restart the device

then re-run the application

it working fine..

Answer (score -1):

Has your provisioning profile expired? Is the profile you are using able to provision the app you are installing?

Comment: This isn't really an answer but a guess that should just be a comment.